# Other dll being used in place of one being referenced

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have two DLLs with the same name. For the sake of this question let's say they are both named MyProject.

Now the OLD MyProject would have the same namespaces, same classes, etc, but it is not the same as the new one entirely.

Now if in my main project decides it wants to use the new one of the same name while taking out the old one, what would you say is the problem when going through a debugging of the application the OLD MyProject gets called instead of the NEW MyProject. The reason I know the old one is being called is because the breakpoints do not endup in the new one's project source code, and because there are actions the old one does that the new one does not...

What could be the problem? I encounter no errors of course, but it is not using my new DLL even though I have made the reference for the new one... Is there some sort of solution cache I need to clear in such a scenario?

Comment: the old version could be stored in the GAC. and it needs to be deleted from there.

Comment: Have you cleaned and rebuilt your project?

Comment: And when I remove the OLD version of MyProject from the GAC will the new one takes its place upon debugging/building my project with the NEW MyProject?

Comment: Yes, it should be. Because once you delete the old dll from GAC, you will not find it again.

Comment: Thank you. I will give this a try tomorrow and see if it resolves my issue, and if no one posts an answer by then I will post the results as the answer.

Comment: Or not tomorrow, but when I get back to this problem in my project, which may be awhile.

Comment: Have you cleaned out your obj and bin folders? That can cause this problem sometimes, I don't know why. Build->Clean solution from VS IDE should do it, otherwise just manually delete them and full rebuild.

Comment: I will also give that a try as both approaches I have not tried yet.

Comment: @HappyLee make your comment an answer and I will gladly accept it. That definitely was the problem as I found TWO MyProject DLL's in my GAC and after deleting them and starting over with the new build, I get the desired results. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the old version could be stored in the GAC. and it needs to be deleted from there. @JBeck I'm glad it worked. Good luck :)

Comment: As expressed in the comments above: this was the issue. My application was using the old version via the GAC instead of actually using the newly built one within my bin/obj folder of my project. Thanks!